# Object properties lost using pickle with class derived from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, class

I am trying to update pickling behavior for a derived class, but I cannot get object properties to be saved in the pickling.

```
import pandas as pd

class Fruit(pd.DataFrame): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fruit, self).__init__()
        self.codebook={3:4}

sdf = Fruit()

sdf.codebook ={1:2}

import pickle

with open('mypickle.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(sdf, f)
with open('mypickle.pickle') as f:
    loaded_obj = pickle.load(f)        
assert  loaded_obj.__class__ == Fruit
assert loaded_obj.codebook
```

The final assert fails. `AttributeError: 'Fruit' object has no attribute 'codebook'`

If my class definition is instead `class Fruit(): pass` then it works alright.

How can I pickle my object and include the new "dot" properties (`.codebook`)?

(This question is related to an open project to add survey data codebook information and functionality to the Pandas DataFrame class: https://github.com/cpbl/surveypandas )

Update:

I have tried replacing DataFrame.to_pickle with Fruit's own, which directly uses pickle.dump(self), and that fails in the same way. (Why?)

Here is an unpretty effort which succeeds in recording everything but results in something that cannot be understood by pandas.read_pickle(). Also this seems unnecessarily awkward:

```
from pandas import DataFrame 
import cPickle as pkl

class Fruit(DataFrame): 
    def __init__(self, data=None, codebook =None):
        super(Fruit, self).__init__(data)
        self.codebook=codebook
    def to_pickle(self, path, compression='infer',
              protocol= pkl.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL):
        """ See pandas.io.pickle and pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle """
        from pandas.io.pickle import to_pickle as pandas_to_pickle
        return pandas_to_pickle( {'o': self, 'c':self.codebook}, path, compression=compression, protocol=protocol)

sdf = Fruit({'foo':[1,2,3]}, codebook={1:2})
sdf.to_pickle('mypickle.pickle')

with open('mypickle.pickle') as f:
    loaded_obj = pkl.load(f)
sdf2 = Fruit(loaded_obj['o'], codebook = loaded_obj['c'])

assert sdf2.__class__ == Fruit
assert sdf2.codebook
```

Comment: I don't know much about pandas myself, but I'd guess it's types have custom behavior set up to allow their pickling, and that behavior doesn't handle your extra attributes. You probably need to add extra methods to your class to ensure that both your part of the data, and pandas' part gets saved properly. I'd check which of the methods documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) are implemented by the `DataFrame` class you're inheriting from, and then dive into the implementation details so that you can extend it to work with your derived class.